# How to fix this "gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/hash/WebstormProjects/CaseStudyFrontEnd/node_modules/node-sass/build'"?

Tags: typescript, ubuntu, angular7

Configure error log:

> gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/hash/WebstormProjects/CaseStudyFrontEnd/node_modules/node-sass/build'
>   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
>   gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/hash/WebstormProjects/CaseStudyFrontEnd/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
>   gyp ERR! cwd /home/hash/WebstormProjects/CaseStudyFrontEnd/node_modules/node-sass
>   gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
>   gyp ERR! not ok 
>   Build failed with error code: 1

Tried all the solutions from the internet on this error. When I execute `npm install` or `sudo npm install` nothing happens if I execute `npm update` or `sudo npm update`.

I have tried all other commands related to the permission handling but still gets this error.

> Unable to save binary /home/hash/WebstormProjects/CaseStudyFrontEnd/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/hash/WebstormProjects/CaseStudyFrontEnd/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
>       at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
>       at sync (/home/hash/WebstormProjects/CaseStudyFrontEnd/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
>       at Function.sync (/home/hash/WebstormProjects/CaseStudyFrontEnd/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
>       at checkAndDownloadBinary (/home/hash/WebstormProjects/CaseStudyFrontEnd/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
>       at Object. (/home/hash/WebstormProjects/CaseStudyFrontEnd/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>     errno: -13,
>     code: 'EACCES',
>     syscall: 'mkdir',
>     path: '/home/hash/WebstormProjects/CaseStudyFrontEnd/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

Comment: you get this when you do "npm install" only ... or when you do "npm install something" ?

Comment: **npm install** only

Comment: you can't do that... you use npm install with a package only